# Does artifactory provide certificate based authtication for docker registry

Tags: artifactory

I am looking about certificates based authentication instead of username and password in artifactory docker registry logging.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that Artifactory don't have this capability, however, as you will have to implement reverse proxy in front of Artifactory for working with Docker you might be able to implement this capability there.

Comment: Hi I can see this authentication link on artifactory website
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Authentication

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on reverse proxy. How can I authenticate to artifactory registry via certificates using reverse proxy.